# Batch file, calling an exe that has PAUSE in it, how to skip?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, skip

```
forfiles /p "P:\a3\" /s /m *.wss /c "cmd /c dewssdos @file"
```

DeWssDos.exe, that I call here has a PAUSE in it and I can not edit the exe.

How do I skip the PAUSE from within my code?

Comment: Maybe `echo y | dewssdos`  will work ... http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the pause would be passed by just hitting Y and a new line.

```
forfiles /p "P:\a3\" /s /m *.wss /c "cmd /c echo y &echo.|dewssdos @file"
```

I hope this could help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer!

I am sorry to have wasted your time. Unfortunately I totally overlooked an option in the DOS Tool itself... -P disables the pause. Oh boy. :)

Anyone that's working with Mikero's DeWssDos tool, try this:

forfiles /p "Path\To\Files" /s /m *.wss /c "cmd /c dewssdos -P @file"